# android list files contained in assets subfolder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I create some folders into assets. Each folder contains files that I would like to list. I am using following code but I always get a null value for fileList. Thank you.

I used, `listFiles("/assets/images/","nothing");`

```
private void listFiles(String dirFrom, String dirTo) {


        File f = new File(dirFrom);

        String fileList[] = f.list();

            if (fileList != null)
            {   
                for ( int i = 0;i<fileList.length;i++)
                {
                    Log.d("",fileList[i]); 
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll probably want to do this:

```
private void listFiles(String dirFrom) {
        Resources res = getResources(); //if you are in an activity
        AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
        String fileList[] = am.list(dirFrom);

            if (fileList != null)
            {   
                for ( int i = 0;i<fileList.length;i++)
                {
                    Log.d("",fileList[i]); 
                }
            }
    }
```

Also your function call should be: `listFiles("images");` if you want to list images.

Comment: how to get the file name?

Comment: @The_Lazy_Man Isn't the array of strings returned by the `Assetmanager.list()` method what you want?

Comment: yes, you are right. But I am facing new problem. can't get the resource ID to initialize an ImageView. Because asset file not provide me the that. Thanks for you reply. :)

Comment: @The_Lazy_Man Files in assets don't get ids, you're forced to use the methods of the `AssetManager` and build the bitmap on your own(and then set it on the `ImageView`).

Comment: ya, I am going on your way. will give you feedback after that.

Comment: it's rather:
String[] fileList = am.list(dirFrom);
also, fileList is always not null, even if no files are found or path is not found, but Exception might be raised. So should be surrounded by try catch.

Answer (score 7):

Simplest would surely be this:

```
String[] fileList = getAssets().list("images");
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of @user's answer, in **Kotlin** [recursive]

```
fun listAssetFiles(context: Context, path: String,block:(isDir:Boolean,path:String)->Unit):Boolean{
    try {
        val list = context.assets.list(path)
        list?.also {files->
            if (files.isNotEmpty()) {
                for (file in files) {
                    val relativePath=if (path.isEmpty()) file else "$path${File.separatorChar}$file"
                    if (!listAssetFiles(context,relativePath,block))
                        block.invoke(false,relativePath) else block.invoke(true,relativePath)
                }
            } else return false
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

How to use :

```
    val fileList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val folderList = mutableListOf<String>()
    listAssetFiles(getApplication(), "my/sample/folder") // or empty for the root folder 
    { isDir, path ->
        if (isDir) folderList.add(path) else fileList.add(path)
    }
```